Подскажите, правильно ли я понял и выполнил задание из учебника "Изучаем Python" Эрик Мэтиз
Как нужно/можно было выполнить задание 7.5 в соответствии с пройденной главой. Знаю что есть масса вариантов, но какие то усовершенствования не интересуют, т.к. эти варианты еще не изучены, хочется знать правильно ли я усваиваю материал или же использую топорные и банальные способы из других глав. (Глава 7 стр.128, задание стр.138) "Изучаем Python" Эрик Мэтиз
Здание: 7.5. Билеты в кино: кинотеатр установил несколько вариантов цены на билеты в зависимости от возраста посетителя. Для посетителей младше 3 лет билет бесплатный; в возрасте от 3 до 12 билет стоит $10; наконец, если возраст посетителя больше 12, билет стоит $15. Напишите цикл, который предлагает пользователю ввести возраст и выводит цену билета.
Что получилось у меня:
age = 'Введите свой возраст, чтобы узнать цену билета: '

while age:

    message = input(age)
    message = int(message)

    if message < 3:
        print("Стоимость билета 0 рублей")
        break
    elif message >=3 and message < 12:
        print("Стоимость билета 1000 рублей.")
        break
    else:
        print("Стоимость билета 1500 рублей.")
        break


Цикл делает только одну итерацию. Думаю Мэтиз имел ввиду что пользователь может вводит возраст много раз, и каждый раз получает стоимость.

Неправильно работаете с input и обработкой вводимых данных. Неправильно организуется цикл. Даже если запускается в результате. Неправильно описано значение 12 в условии. Сначала до 12, а потом больше 12. А 12 куды?

12 не включительно, а значит относится к группе билетов за 1500, почему не правильно ?

Русский хорошо знаете? Написано: до 12 билет стоит $10. Не написано включительно. Далее: больше 12, билет стоит $15. Не написано больше или равно.

Так не написано, что 12 включительно, трактовать можно по-разному. Что за придирка, на работу кода это никак не влияет, если перевести $10 в рубли получится тоже не 1000 руб. ?? )))

Какие рубли? Надо было условие задачи писать в рублях! Я что-то путаю? "стоит $10" - о какой валюте речь? Насчёт 12 я даже не буду пытаться спорить. Бесполезно. Я уже объяснил "особенности русского языка" в условии.

Так тут не про русский язык, тут надо на другой язык смотреть

В программировании нет понятия "трактовать". Это где-то там, в соцсетях или СМИ. Программист должен иметь чёткие, до самой последней буквы, задания, прежде чем начнёт их реализовывать в коде. В математике, кстати, тоже. В нормальной школе, у нормального учителя нормальному ученику чётко объясняется понятие интервала, отрезка. От этого зависит результат решения примера.

И да, в программировании от простого пробела не там, где надо, логика может измениться до неузнаваемости. Привыкайте, программирование - это не разговоры разговаривать. Когда перед Вами будут сотни строк кода, которые надо проверять в поисках логической ошибки, понимание важности строгости постановки задачи появится быстро.


как написали в комментариях, break стоит убрать.
получение возврата можно записать красивее: age = int(input()) (и везде вместо message использовать age)
во втором if'е можно убрать условие age >= 3`, т. к. оно следует из того, что первое условие не выполнилось.
можно создать переменную cost, чтобы убрать повторения print'а.

message = "Введите свой возраст, чтобы узнать цену билета: "
while True:
    age = int(input(message))
   
    if age < 3:
        cost = 0
    elif age < 12:
        cost = 1000
    else:
        cost = 1500
    print(f"Стоимость билета {cost} рублей.")


Введу я в качестве возраста "ввв" и... Или ничего не введу вообще и тыцну на энтер...

@FoxFox, ну и не страшно.

Конечно, не расстреляют. Но автор вопроса новичок! Он хочет узнать, насколько он правильно мыслит. Так пусть научится правильно мыслить с самого начала! В программировании не идеи занимают больше всего времени и требуют энергии, а защита от дурака и функциональность для выполнения требуемой задачи. О профессии "тестировщик ПО" слыхали? Работа этих людей - ломать код с первой строки и до последней. Чтоб писатель малость в себя пришёл и начал писать как следует, а не квецал лишь бы живо.

print(f"Стоимость билета {cost} рублей.") строчка для меня вообще не понятна, начал изучение python с этой книги, делал исключительно по тому, что было изучено потому так криво, спасибо за оценку, буду стремиться к такому уровню )

Код написал с break для логического завершения программы, а в целом понимание его уместности в этом коде есть.

print(f"Стоимость билета {cost} рублей.") - поясняю. В фигурных скобках прописывается переменная, значение которой будет подставлено вместо {cost} при выводе на экран. Буквально, если cost=15, на экран будет выведено: Стоимость билета 15 рублей. f перед кавычками означает вызов функции подстановки. Иначе было бы выведено: Стоимость билета {cost} рублей.

print("-" * 50 + "\nПродажа билетов в кино:\n" + "-" * 50)

while True:

 ok = True
 age = input("\nУкажите свой возраст для того, чтоб узнать цену билета: ")
 try:
  age = abs(int(float(age.replace(",", "."))))
 except Exception as e:
  print(f"Указано ошибочное значение возраста! Попробуйте ещё раз! Подробнее: {e}")
  ok = False

 if ok:
  if age < 3: print("Билет бесплатен!")
  elif age >= 3 and age <= 12: print("Стоимость билета $10!")
  else: print("Стоимость билета $15!")


Ой, уже один оценщик нашёлся. Чё непонравилося? Не работает?

отлично написано, все четко. добавил плюсик.

Код классный, но не тот уровень. Интересовало правильно ли было сделано задание согласно главе. Так как в твоем варианте, я научусь еще не скоро )

Я ж написал в комментариях к заданию то, что я думаю о Вашей программе. И в комментах к другому ответу. Fox Fox. Ничего заумного в моём коде нет. Это можно объяснить за 5 минут, даже в комментах. Я этим и занимаюсь. Помогаю школьникам решать задачки и поясняю совершенно простенькие вещи типа try... except, int, float, replace онлайн. Через месяц будете сами смеяться, узнав насколько это всё простые базовые вещи в Питоне.

Хотелось бы, но думаю позже, т.к. занимаюсь в свободное от работы время, а его не так много )

Ну, здесь не курсы. Мне не дадут тут разглагольствовать. Я могу дать пояснения по конкретному примеру, но базовые вещи в учебнике надо учить самому сначала. Тем более, я консультирую онлайн. Писать лекции просто глупо.
